# How to minimize the vertex of the graph by substituting cycles?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

How can I minimize the number of vertices of the directed graph by removing circuits? Is there any algorithms that can be adapted here?

There already is a question about removing the cycles in graphs, but I am particularly asking about MINIMIZING THE NUMBER OF VERTICES by removing the cycles in graphs

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the solution for your problem is to simply turn cycles into a single node, sure, you can do that easily.

When you execute Breadth-First Search (BSF) or Depth-First Search (DFS), you will find cycles (i.e. if you mark the path you step into, once you can reach an already marked node, you have found a cycle). Hence, you can easily find cycles by storing the predecessor of each node you visit, that is, if you are in node `u` and you go to node `v`, you can store `p[v] = u`, so if you find some node `w` already visited in the adjacency list of `v`, you can walk back, parent by parent, until you find `w` and you have all nodes from that cycles.

I cannot guarantee any property of completeness from this algorithm, so if you can freely preprocess your graph, you can run DFSs on it until the graph is unchanged by it, otherwise run it a certain number `n` of times that you find is efficient.

```
void FindCycles(vector<Node> nodes){
    int p[nodes.size()];
    bool mark[nodes.size()]; //set all to false
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(nodes[0].id);
    while(s.size()){
        int u = s.pop();
        mark[u] = true;
        for(int v : nodes[u].adjs){
            p[v] = u;
            if(mark[v]) {
                //found a cycle, call some method to reduce the graph
                cout<<v<<" belongs to the cycle"<<endl;
                while(u != v){
                    cout<<u<<" belongs to the cycle"<<endl;
                    u = p[u];
                }
                break;
            }
            else{
                s.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```